# what is `ssh-agent bin/bash` and why I have to `ssh-add` everytime

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, git, bashrc

I have to run the following commands each time I restart:

```
ssh-agent /bin/bash
ssh-add ~/.ssh/key_rsa
```

First question is why is `/bin/bash` necessary and what it is used for?

Second, Is it ok I run these commands every time on restart, or should I put this in `.bashrc` or somewhere so I don't have to `ssh-add` everytime.

Note that I use `screen` and every screen tab is different and I have to run these commands for every screen tab.

**Edit:**

For example when I need to push to github I need to do `ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_rsa`, but this doesn't work unless I do `ssh-agent /bin/bash` first.

This might be related to `screen` because plain `ssh-agent` doesn't work, and ssh-agent is already running, yet I have to do `ssh-agent /bin/bash`.

Comment: Just curious what problem you are trying to solve - how do you determine "I have to run the following" ; to get an ssh key in each login I have the following as  a single line in my .bashrc "eval `keychain --eval id_rsa id_dsa`"

Comment: @nwaltham for example I run these commands if I want to push to github, I need to do `ssh-add github_rsa` if I haven't done already. (`ssh-add` doesn't work by default so I have to run `ssh-agent /bin/bash` first). Can you explain your solution a little more, what is `keychain` and post it as answer. Also see my edit please.

Comment: You should check out ssh-ident if you haven't found or heard of it yet. It's obviously been a while since the op, but you never know. It fixes your issue of having to always restart the agent and add your keys - and it does it in just about the most secure way currently available ... unless I've missed something. https://github.com/ccontavalli/ssh-ident

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ssh-agent` is a daemon that caches the decrypted ssh key in memory when you `ssh-add` it so that you don't have to type in the password to decrypt it each time `ssh` tries to use it for authentication. It being cached in memory means that the next time `ssh-agent` is started the key has to be decrypted and added to the agent again, which is why you need to `ssh-add` it again.

The `/bin/bash` part isn't actually necessary. Normally when you start `ssh-agent` it will print some environment variables to stdout which are meant to be `eval`ed so that `ssh` knows where the `ssh-agent` socket is. If you instead give `ssh-agent` a command when you start it, it will run that command with the environment variables set instead.

This means that the bash instance you're using after running the command is a subshell of the one you were using before. The issue with adding that to your `.bashrc` is that the new shell `ssh-agent` starts would run `ssh-agent` again, causing a recursive loop, which you don't want. Instead you might want to just start [`ssh-agent` in your `.bash_profile`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys#ssh-agent) and eval the output instead of starting a subshell, and then use `ssh-add` yourself manually once each time you log in.

Another option would be to use the [GNOME Keyring](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME_Keyring)'s SSH agent emulation instead of using `ssh-agent`. Unlike `ssh-agent` that doesn't save your passphrase, the GNOME Keyring will store the passphrase to the key in a keyring so you don't have to add keys manually.

Comment: How is this related to me using `screen`. Also `/bin/bash` part is necessary in my case, when I run only `ssh-agent` and do a `ssh-add -l` it errors: `Failed connection to auth agent`. What could be the problem about that? Finally is it a good practice to put `ssh-add id_rsa` to `bashrc` along with `ssh-agent`? Thanks @kyrias.

Comment: It's related because you don't have the environmental variables set in `screen`. When you start `ssh-agent` it will print some output containing commands to set variables (`foo="bar"`) and then exports them to the environment (`export foo`), and since you haven't ran those commands `ssh-add` won't be able to find the `ssh-agent` socket (The `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` part of the output from `ssh-agent`).

Comment: Re: `ssh-add id_rsa`, if your key doesn't have a passphrase set it will work fine, but then `ssh-agent` would be rather pointless to use, and if your ssh key *does* have a passphrase it might not work because it possibly won't be able to prompt you for the passphrase to decrypt the key.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use keychain http://www.funtoo.org/Keychain

Keychain helps you to manage ssh and GPG keys in a convenient and secure manner. It acts as a frontend to ssh-agent and ssh-add, but allows you to easily have one long running ssh-agent process per system, rather than the norm of one ssh-agent per login session.

Firstly you would install it according to your distribution for debian/ubuntu

```
apt-get install keychain
```

Then add the following to ~/.bashrc file:

```
eval `keychain --eval id_rsa`
```

Comment: This is the best way to go.   MUCH better than prompting every single time you subshell.